# Limited Solution Polishing in CPLEX

Tags: optimization, cplex

I am using CPLEX to solve an optimization problem and I have explicitly defined the time after which polishing should take place. However, I notice that even before polishing starts, the log displays "Starting limited solution polishing". I have not been able to find any documentation explaining what this is about. I am therefore, looking for an explanation about limited solution polishing vs traditional solution polishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When CPLEX comes close to the timelimit that was specified, it may decide to start this 'Limited solution polishing'.  This is pretty close to the real 'solution polishing' algorithm, although not exactly the same, hence the distinction.

Comment: I am looking at running simulations in CPLEX for different optimization times, and I notice that limited solution polishing is used only sometimes. This tends to produce results with no trend, i.e. as optimization time increases, I notice I may sometimes get worst results compared to when using a shorter optimization time as limited soln polishing is being used. Is there anyway to disable this to make my simulations more consistent?

Comment: If you specify a deterministic time limit instead of a non-deterministic one, CPLEX should not use 'limited solution polishing'. And if you specify when CPLEX should start solution polishing, CPLEX should do that. You may want to check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_20.1.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/heuristics/46_soln_polish.html